# Dúvida na comparação de variáveis

Tags: php, comparação

Existe outra forma de desenvolver essa comparação?

```
$numero = 1234;
$a = 1111;
$b = 2222;
$c = 3333;
$d = 4444;

if ($numero == $a or $numero == $b or $numero == $c or $numero == $d) {
    echo "O número existe";
    } else {
    echo "Não existe o número";
}
```

Queria saber se existe outra forma de manipular essa comparação

```
  ($numero == $a or $numero == $b or $numero == $c or $numero == $d)
```

Comment: Cuidado a diferença entre `or` e `||` é a prioridade. veja no manual [operadores lógicos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: No código original as variáveis recebem os valores `$numero = 0.00005670;
$a = 0.00008756;
$b = 0.00006745;
$c = 0.00006754;
$d = 0.00008734;` Qual a diferença? Os dois não funcionariam da mesma forma nesta situação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se precisa achar(comparar) um valor, você pode transformar essas variáveis(`$a, $b, $c e $d`) em um array e depois pesquisar com a [in_array()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), o primeiro argumento(`$numero`) é o que você deseja buscar e o segundo(`$arr`) em qual variável isso deve ser feito.

```
$numero = 1234;
$a = 1111;
$b = 2222;
$c = 3333;
$d = 4444;

$arr = array($a, $b, $c, $d);

if (in_array($numero, $arr)) {
    echo "O número existe";
} else {
    echo "Não";
}
```

Comment: Dependendo da necessidade, pode ser interessante usar o terceiro parâmetro do in_array - strict - com o valor true, para que ele faça verificação de tipo também.