# Como varrer uma array de uma variável e comparar com outra variavel?

Tags: php

Tenho o código abaixo funciona bem, porém gostaria que as informações em strings fosse pega em uma array por exemplo:

```
$array = array('cia','Cia','dia','Dia','hoje');
```

e verificar se uma dessas palavras acima de tem na variável texto.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso ?

```
$texto = $_REQUEST['text'];
    if((strpos($texto,'cia')!==false || strpos($texto,'Cia')!==false || strpos($texto,'dia')!==false || strpos($texto,'prod')!==false) || (strpos($texto,'daily')!==false || strpos($texto,'Daily')!==false || strpos($texto,'prod')!==false) || strpos($texto,'hoje')!==false || strpos($texto,'produ%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20di%C3%A1ria')!==false) {

     //pega a pagina que quero redirecionar
}
```

Comment: Talvez seja duplicata de: [Dúvida na comparação de variáveis](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13207/91)

Answer (score 1):

Troque esses OUs pelo uso da função `in_array()`, ela usa dois argumentos, o primeiro é a string a ser buscada e o segundo os itens que serão comparados.

```
<?php
$texto = $_REQUEST['text'];
$array = array('cia','Cia','dia','Dia','hoje');

if(in_array($texto, $array)){
   echo 'texto encontrado no array';
}
```

Comment: valeu funcionou

Comment: Se essa é a resposta, então sim é uma duplicata, se ele quisesse verificar se na string tive-se alguma das string no meio, então é um pouco mais complexo.